# Drive API using JavaScript and SAML

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, saml-2.0

I can find lots of good examples for using the Google Drive API with JavaScript and OAUTH2, and I can find articles saying that Google API's support SAML 2.0. But I can't find any information about how to use the Drive API using JavaScript and SAML. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

For working with Web Browser SSO profile you need to have AssertionConsumerService URL on your server. I think you can use JavaScript on server side, but you can't use  Web Browser SSO only with user web browser.

You need to have some URL on your server for that. You can read more about SAML 2.0 here https://www.oasis-open.org/standards#samlv2.0. Also, the wiki contains some good images about SAML protocol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0.

Comment: This does not answer the question. On further digging, it appears that SAML can only be used when accessing Google Drive via the Google Drive UI web page. Access via API is restricted to OAUTH2.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You can use the SAML protocol to SSO to Google's OAuth server (if you have that setup w/ your Google App's domain) to get an OAuth access token (as a JWT). You can't send a SAML token to a Google API via JavaScript, however.